# Writing data to a .csv file: only the value from the last iteration of a function (Python, pandas)

Tags: python-2.7, function, csv, pandas

I am writing a code that reads .fits files and distinguishes between bright and dark images. To do this, I read in the image, take a subset of the image pixels, and create a function that determines whether all pixel values in the subset are above a certain threshold. Finally I want to create a .csv file that stores the results.

My function is written as follows:

```
    def function(subset): 
        if np.all(subset > x):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And the function seems to work, returning "True" for a bright image, and "False" for a dark image.

However, the next part does not. The code to create a .csv file is as follows:

```
csv_file = open('new_file.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
for f in filenames:
    writer.writerow([f, function(subset)])

csv_file.close()
```

When I then read the .csv file in as a dataframe, I find that the function return has not been carried over, and all files return a "True" value, whether falsely or correctly. Here is how my dataframe would appear:

```
    "filename"   "function result"
0   file1.fits    True
1   file2.fits    True
2   file3.fits    True
```

Where I know that when executing the function "function(subset)", if file2.fits were a "dark" image it would return the value "False".

Any suggestions? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you use function in pandas? `df['result'] = df['filename'].apply(function)` ? How is define subset?

Comment: I realised that I hadn't called the function at any point. However, when I included your code `df['result'] = df['filename'].apply(function)` I receive the error message: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`, which I assume is because I'm trying to call a result that may return True/False?

Comment: Exactly. Need return True False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need return `True` or `False` from function called by [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
np.random.seed(1)

def function(x):
    #print (x)
    #sample generator 
    y = np.random.choice([True, False], 1)[0]
    if y:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df['result'] = df['filename'].apply(function)
print (df)
     filename  result
0  file1.fits   False
1  file2.fits   False
2  file3.fits    True
```

Comment: Hi, does this code randomly assign a True/False value to each value of x? If so, is there a way to edit that so that True or False is assigned to specific values of x?

Comment: Can you explain more logic for it?

Comment: The code you shared, where `function(x)` is defined as `y = np.random.choice([True, False], 1)[0]`, returns a value of either "True" or "False" for each row within my dataframe. Whether the row receives "True" or "False" is determined randomly, correct? That is, there are no criteria for assigning "True" or "False" other than a random True/False generator. What I'd like to do is assign "True" or "False" based on criteria relating to the intrinsic value of each row of my dataframe.

Comment: Exactly you are right. I create sample data with random function for random True and False values. And question is what is your real function for return boolean? What are your criteria with real data?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Each of the rows in the dataframe refers to a .fits image file that contains pixels of a certain value. I would like images that return `True` to contain pixels with higher values: for instance, if 80% of pixels in an image file have values > 6000, then I would like my function to return `True`; if <80% of pixels have values > 6000, `False`.

Comment: And need help with this code right? Can you create some data sample for it? Maybe the best is send it to my email on my profile. Also do you have some code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Thank you - that would be really useful. I'll send you the code I have so far, along with two .fits files with and without an eruption that can illustrate what I am trying to do.